# Identify and remove strange characters

Tags: python, shell, command-line

What command can I use to identify and remove certain strange characters that form "words" such as:

```
í‰äó_
í€Œ¢í‰ä‰åí‰ä‹¢
ití€Œ¢í‰ä‰åí‰ä‹¢
í‰äóìgo
```

from a series of files? Those are some examples...
I want to remove such occurrences.

Comment: How do you define "strange"? Do you want to filter out characters that are not explicitly basic letters a-z?

Comment: it's basically a series of characters that don't make sense in english. Punctuation is accepted like ? ! . it's just those random characters that appear together as "words"

Comment: then you want to use pythons string module and check to see if the line from the file has characters in string.printable. F3AR3DLEGEND responded to your question providing that option, look at his answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `string` module after you've gotten the data from the file:

```
import string
final_str = ''
for char in my_str:
    if char in string.printable:
        final_str += char
```

Alternative one-liner:

```
''.join([str(char) for char in my_str if char in string.printable])
```

Comment: I have a text file and � in my string and want to remove it from the string. `If '�' in line: continue` does not recognize it. I pasted it [here](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) and got 1character, 3 bytes. Does not help. In python, I get ï¿½. I do line wise editing, so your char based solution does not help to do it in one rush. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

How about a regex sub?

something like:

```
import re

clean_name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\._-]', '', dirty_name)
```

Add to the regex any other allowed char.

Comment: Explanation: If not one of the chars in brackets in dirtyname, it will write nothing and return cleanname.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `shell` and `command-line`, here you go

```sh
$ tr -cd [:graph:][:space:] < foo.txt
_

it
go
```