# Some column errors

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I loaded a .csv file successfully.
I picked some specific column to fillna with mean that reads like this on spreadsheet "Temperature Difference¬†or¬†Airflow Temperature" but should actually read like this "Temperature Difference or Airflow Temperature".
I keep getting errors that call back to that row.

What I have done:
Edited the csv columns and taken out the cross sign but that just gives me a Unicode Decode error

For example: output.csv contains the following columns
Temperature Difference¬†  and Pressure Difference with some null values.

```
data.columns = 'Temperature Difference','Pressure Difference'
```

with no funny character in it.

```
data['Temperature Difference'].fillna(data['Temperature Difference'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

gives `KeyError: 'Temperature Difference'`

Comment: This post might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137088/identify-and-remove-strange-characters

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Please see additional examples. Thanks

Comment: I think it should be `data.columns = ['Temperature Difference','Pressure Difference']`. Try assigning a `list` of  values to `data.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column values with a list. You can do this manually with `data.columns = ['Temperature Difference', 'Pressure Difference']`.

If you want to do so without knowing the names in advance, you can do either of the following.

```
data.columns = [''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in col]) for col in data.columns]
```

or

```
def non_ascii_to_space(s):
    return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in s])

data.columns = [non_ascii_to_space(col) for col in data.columns]
```

(based on [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space))

Comment: Thanks Eric the first one worked. Thanks to everyone who replied me